# videoplayer can't decode subtitles

Tags: video, codecs

While playing video it says that PGS subtitle decoder is required to play.

Is there anyway I can install these codecs from, as Ubuntu software center doesn't find it?

Thank you.

Comment: What video player are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to play file; no PGS subtitle decoder for Totem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142253/unable-to-play-file-no-pgs-subtitle-decoder-for-totem)